# Multi-lang website: Is this a smart way of doing it?

Tags: php, cordova, multilingual

```
function title_of_page() {
// Get the user's location
$user_location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//Find just the filename
$filename = pathinfo($user_location, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

if ($user_location == "") {           
   switch ($filename) {
        case 'intro': echo 'introduction'; break;
        case 'about': echo 'about the author'; break;
        case 'foreword': echo 'foreword'; break;
        case 'pottery': echo 'pottery'; break;
        case 'gold_jewelery': echo 'jewelry in bahrain'; break;
        case 'metalwork': echo 'metalwork'; break;
        case 'weaving': echo 'weaving'; break;
        case 'glass': echo 'glass industry'; break;
        case 'woodwork': echo 'woodwork'; break;
        case 'plant': echo 'Plant-product handicrafts'; break;
        case 'calligraphy': echo 'arabic calligraphy'; break;
        case 'thanks': echo 'thanks & appreciation'; break;
        case 'craft': echo 'craft centres'; break;
        case 'videos': echo 'videos'; break;
        case 'pano': echo 'panoramic'; break;

        // These are the crafts subpages
        case 'jasra_handicrafts': echo 'Al Jasra Handicrafts Center'; break;
        case 'jasra_training': echo 'Al Jasra Training Center'; break;
        case 'capital_mall': echo 'Capital Mall'; break;
        case 'craft_industries': echo 'The Craft Industries Development Centre'; break;
    default: echo '<img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">'; break;} 

} else {

// ARABIC TITLES
switch ($user_location) {
    case '/ar/intro.php': echo 'مقدمة'; break;
    case '/ar/about.php': echo 'نبذة عن الكاتب'; break;
    case '/ar/foreword.php.php': echo 'تقديم'; break;
    case '/ar/pottery.php': echo 'الفخار'; break;
    case '/ar/gold_jewelery.php': echo 'حلي الذهب والفضة واللآلئ'; break;
    case '/ar/metalwork.php': echo 'الأعمال المعدنية'; break;
    case '/ar/weaving.php': echo 'النسيج والتطريز وتفصيل الملابس'; break;
    case '/ar/glass.php': echo 'صناعة الزجاج'; break;
    case '/ar/woodwork.php': echo 'الأشغال الخشبية'; break;
    case '/ar/plant.php': echo 'صناعة المنتجات من المواد المأخوذة من النباتات'; break;
    case '/ar/calligraphy.php': echo 'الخط العربي'; break;
    case '/ar/thanks.php': echo 'شكر وتقدير'; break;
    case '/ar/craft.php': echo 'المراكز الحرفية'; break;
    case '/ar/panoramic.php': echo 'بانوراما'; break;

    // These are the crafts subpages
    case '/ar/jasra_handicrafts.php': echo 'مركز الجسرة للحرف اليدوية'; break;
    case '/ar/jasra_training.php': echo 'مركز الجسرة للتدريب'; break;
    case '/ar/capital_mall.php': echo 'بمجمع العاصمة'; break;
    case '/ar/craft_industries.php': echo 'مركز تنمية الصناعات الحرفية'; break;
default: echo '<img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png">'; break;}
}
}
```

This is currently the code i'm using. I'm building a PhoneGap app for a client of mine and the app is stationery (as in, client doesn't want a CMS). Anyway, what I want to happen is that when the user is viewing the English side of the app, it'll show the English titles however when the user is on the Arabic side of the app it'll show the same titles in Arabic.
Just wondering if i'm going the right way..?

Comment: You get the language from something like `?lang=ar` and save it in a cookie.

Comment: I think it would be better to use an array `$lang[]` in a `lang.ar.php` file, and then all what you would have to do is to Check the `lang` from the `$_COOKIE` or `$_GET`. ( Example: the `lang.ar.php` would have `$lang['intro'] = مقدمة` whereas the `lang.en.php` would have `$lang['intro'] = intro`) but your `index.php` is always calling for `$lang['intro']` no matter what the language is.